# Data validation on number of numerical characters in a string

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula

Trying to add formula to data validation that checks whether a string is either 6 numerical digits, or 6 numerical digits with hyphens or spaces. E.g.

123456
Or
12-34-56
Or
12 34 56

The string could also contain leading zeros.

The user should not be able to input a string that differs from the above formats, so

123-456
Or
1234567
....for example

Would prefer not to use VBA, but am struggling to make this into a data validation formula.

Any ideas would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=AND(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""),"-","")*1<=999999,SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""),"-","")*1>=1,LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""),"-",""))=6)
```

This formula removes hyphens and spaces, then checks if the number is 6 digits and that it falls between 1 and 999999. If there are any letters/symbols, the *1 part will cause an error.

Edit:
@JvdV id right. I misread your requirements. Here is my second attempt:

```
=AND(OR(ISNUMBER(MATCH("??-??-??",A1,0)),ISNUMBER(MATCH("?? ?? ??",A1,0)),AND(IFERROR(A1*1,0)<=999999,IFERROR(A1*1,0)>=1)),ISNUMBER(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","")," ","")*1))
```

Here is what it allows and doesn't allow:

[image]

Comment: It will also allow for very different formats than just the `123456`, `12-34-56` or `12 34 56` unfortunatley.

Comment: @JvDv is right. Please see my second attempt.

Comment: @Bryan Rock thanks that works well, but had left an issue with the cell formatting. If I format as Text, it won't allow me to input 123456. I can get around this by formatting as custom 000000 or 00-00-00 but this pads a leading zero if the user only inputs 5 digits, which I wanted to avoid, the user must only be able to input 6 numbers from 0 to 9. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Just added *1 in a few spots so text will be converted to number.

Comment: Thanks, That gets around the format issue but now allows input of <6 digits. E.g. 12345, 123 etc.

Comment: Oh I thought you wanted to allow that. In that case you can add a `len` restriction to the `and` statement or you can change the inequality to >=100000.

Comment: Perfect thank you very much, went with changing the inequality

Comment: Still wrong I'm afraid @brittd and will allow for things like `12--3-45` and `1------2`. You may even swap the hyphens for spaces for it to still accept input. I'll admit it's a rather hard query to fullfill, but this is not the answer just yet.